# Turn Safari Picture-in-Picture into a 'real' window?

Tags: mac, safari, windows, video

When using Picture in Picture with Safari on the Mac, macOS pins the video player to the corners of the screen and only allows you to resize the window to a maximum of about 1/5 of the total size of the screen.

Is there a way to make that video player into a 'real' window - one that can be dragged and placed as any other window, and one that is able to be resized as any other window as well? I'm thinking of a hidden preference, extension, or some other mechanism to bypass the corner and resize limitations.

I enjoy picture-in-picture for the ability to strip window chrome from often busy video-player websites. But, it's such a weird limitation that you can't put that window wherever you want.